# How to delete the local data store that is created by Cloudant Synch

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have an app based on the Bluelist example, there is a local data store created to be in synch with the Cloudant database on Bluemix. I have deleted the DB on Bluemix backend, but the application is still getting data from the local store. Is there a problem with the synch? Should it deletes the local store when the Cloudant DB is deleted?

I tried to locate the local data store to delete it. I can see the path is printed out. But I can not find it on my Mac. Where can I find it?

> /data/data/com.ibm.bluelist/app_BlueListDatastores/todosdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the local data store, in Android studio, Tools > AVD Manager, select the emulator, on the right hand menu, select "Wipe Data".

Answer (score 0):

The local store for the Bluelist application is actually stored on the device. To delete the local data store completely you can delete the application and reinstall it on the device.

I would recommend attempting to replicate with the backend DB first though. This can be accomplished in the iOS application by doing a physical pull down of the list items (dragging your finger from the top of the list down).